# Array is not being saved from Node.js model's object in postgresql database

Tags: node.js, arrays, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a POST function that takes in two users, a user sending a friend request and a user receiving a friend request. After some validation, the user receiving the friend request's username should be added to the user sending the friend request's sentRequestList array. I've tried to do this all sorts of ways, the update function, the set function, and even =. I'm saving the user sending the friend request before returning the object.

SOLVED -

```
userSendingFriendRequest.sentRequestsList = userSendingFriendRequest.sentRequestsList.concat([userReceivingFriendRequestUsername]);
```

Users.js

```
router.post("/send-friend-request", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userSendingFriendRequestUsername, userReceivingFriendRequestUsername } = req.body

    const userSendingFriendRequest = await Users.findOne({ where: ({ username: userSendingFriendRequestUsername }) });

    const userReceivingFriendRequest = await Users.findOne({ where: ({ username: userReceivingFriendRequestUsername }) });

    if (userReceivingFriendRequest == null || userSendingFriendRequest == null || !userSendingFriendRequest || !userReceivingFriendRequest) {
      return res.status(403).send("The user receiving the friend request or the user sending the friend request does not exist")
    }

    if (userSendingFriendRequestUsername === userReceivingFriendRequestUsername) {
      return res.status(403).send("You can't request yourself")
    }

    const array = userSendingFriendRequest.sentRequestsList || [];

    array.push(userReceivingFriendRequestUsername);

    userSendingFriendRequest.set('sentRequestsList', array)

    await userSendingFriendRequest.save()

    return res.status(200).json(userSendingFriendRequest)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
})
```

Users.js (model)

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const Users = sequelize.define("Users", {
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    token: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    userImage: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: ""
    },
    sentRequestsList: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: []
    },
    friendsList: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING, DataTypes.STRING),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: []
    },
  });

  return Users;
};
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")

require("dotenv").config();


// parse incoming requests with JSON payloads
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

const db = require("./models")

// Routers 
const userRouter = require('./routes/Users');
app.use("/api/users", userRouter)

const lettersRouter = require('./routes/Letters');
app.use("/api/letters", lettersRouter)


db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Server Running on port 3001")
  });
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "pg": "^8.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.28.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.0"
  }
}
```

This worked but is extremely ugly (like my code but I'm trying)

```
router.post("/send-friend-request", async (req, res) => {

  const { userSendingFriendRequestUsername, userReceivingFriendRequestUsername } = req.body

  const userSendingFriendRequest = await Users.findOne({ where: ({ username: userSendingFriendRequestUsername }) });

  const userReceivingFriendRequest = await Users.findOne({ where: ({ username: userReceivingFriendRequestUsername }) });

  if (userReceivingFriendRequest == null || userSendingFriendRequest == null) {
    return res.status(403).send("The user receiving the friend request or the user sending the friend request does not exist")
  }

  if (userSendingFriendRequestUsername === userReceivingFriendRequestUsername) {
    return res.status(403).send("You can't request yourself")
  }

  // really weird solution .. this will be revised after proof-of-concept
  const array = []

  for (let i = 0; i < userSendingFriendRequest.sentRequestsList.length; i++) {
    array.push(userSendingFriendRequest.sentRequestsList[i])
  }

  array.push(userReceivingFriendRequestUsername)

  userSendingFriendRequest.sentRequestsList = array

  await userSendingFriendRequest.save()

  return res.status(200).json(userSendingFriendRequest)
})
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is "SOLVED" already